# How to perform two asynchronous operations with async let for two different types? Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to perform asynchronous operations with the **async let** syntax for two different types, so that both of those methods are run in parallel?

I've tried with the **TaskGroup** as well but can't figure this out

```swift
    func getOptionsAndVariants() async {
        do {
            async let options: [ProductOption] = NetworkManager.sharedInstance.getProductOptions(product.id.description)
            async let variants: [ProductVariant] = NetworkManager.sharedInstance.getProductVariants(product.id)
            
            await try options, variants // Wrong syntax
```

Comment: This may be the solution: let (options, variants) = try await (NetworkManager.sharedInstance.getProductOptions(product.id.description), NetworkManager.sharedInstance.getProductVariants(product.id)). Could anyone please confirm that it does run in parallel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
await try options, variants // Wrong syntax
```

To

```
let result = (await options, await variants)
```

Or, if either of the things you are awaiting also requires `try`, put it *before* the respective `await`. For instance if *both* of them requires `try`, you would say

```
let result = (try await options, try await variants)
```

Now result is a *tuple* of two values representing the returned values — `result.0` is the `options` value, and `result.1` is the `variants` value.

And the important thing is that `result` has *no* value until *both* `async let` values have returned — in parallel.

Comment: would it not be okay to use singular 'try' before brackets for both? let result = try await (first, second)?

Comment: As long as it compiles, you'll be fine. The compiler helps you! And the important thing is, if it compiles, _it works_. If you are awaiting both values as a single tuple, your code will wait for both values to arrive, _in parallel_.